# How to pass entire JSON string to Helm chart value?

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can I pass the entire JSON string to a Helm chart value?

I have `values.yml` where the config value should contain entire JSON with a configuration of an application

```
...
config: some JSON here
...
```

and I need to pass this value to a secret template and then mount it as a volume to a Kubernetes pod.

```
{{- $env := default "integration" .Values.env}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-{{ $env }}
type: Opaque
data:
  config.json: {{ .Values.config | b64enc | quote }}
```

However the obvious approach of passing single quoted string like `'{"redis": "localhost:6379"}'` fails because Helm for some reason deletes all double quotes in the string (even if I escape them) so I end up with `{redis: localhost:6379}` which is not a valid JSON.

Is there any other possibility how to pass configuration to the pod all at once without loading template files with `tpl` function and making all needed fields accessible via `values.yml` separately?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If `.Values.config` contains json then you can use it in your templated secret with

```
{{ .Values.config | toJson | b64enc | quote }}
```

It may seem strange to use `toJson` to convert JSON to JSON but helm doesn't natively treat it as JSON until you tell it to. See the SO question [How do I use json variables in a yaml file (Helm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930405/how-do-i-use-json-variables-in-a-yaml-file-helm) for an example of doing this.

Comment: Another way to do it is to put the json in a file at the base of your chart and load it with `{{ .Files.Get "config.json" | b64enc | quote }` or use .Files.Glob with AsSecrets but I guess you specifically want the content in the values file.

Comment: Yes, I need the JSON in `.Values.config` because we use rancher. Therefore we have `questions.yml` in the chart and the value is filled interactively either via rancher CLI or GUI

Answer (score 7):

Here is another suggestion if you want to avoid encoding :

```
env:
  - name: MYCONFIG
  value: {{ .Files.Get "config.json" | toPrettyJson }}
```

According to the [helm docs](https://helm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generate-and-template/), helm uses template functions such as `toPrettyJson` which are supplied by the built-in Go text/template package and the [Sprig template function library](https://helm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generate-and-template/).

Comment: this should be the top answer for entire internet, took me so long to find this

Answer (score 4):

when passing something to --set or --set-string and you don't want helm to interpret it you want to escape every single of=

```
{
[
,
.
]
}
```

with backslash. Remember about your shell that might interpret \ so sometimes you might want to \ or use value in single quotas instead.
Something like this works for me in bash:

```
--set airflow.config.AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS='\{\\\"variables_prefix\\\": \\\"/here-is-my-prefix/'${bamboo_deploy_environment}'/airflow/variables\\\"\, \\\"connections_prefix\\\": \\\"/here-is-my-prefix/'${bamboo_deploy_environment}'/airflow/connections\\\"\}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from the `yaml` file pretty easy like this:

```yaml
# ... values.yaml
myspecialvalue:
  somefield: 'some string'
# ... more stuff if you'd like
```

then inside one of your helm files you can reference it like so:

```yaml
# ... cron.yaml
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: ...
  namespace: ...
spec:
  schedule: ...
  jobTemplate:
    spec:  
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: some-container  
            image: ...
            command: ...
            env:
            - name: SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
              value: {{ .Values.myspecialvalue | toJson | quote }}

# ... more stuff if you'd like
```

this will pass the appropriately quoted `json` string as an environment variable to your pod like so:

```json
'{"somefield": "some string"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to escape  this JSON:

in Notepad++ regex replace of `{{(\w+)}}` to `{{`{{`}}$1{{`}}`}}` helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

helm has introduce a --set-json flag for this purpose refer to https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/