# How to give stringified json value as parameter/variable in Helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Would like to give stringified json as value to a config variable in Helm charts, but it is not accepting it or recognizing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use json variables in a yaml file (Helm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930405/how-do-i-use-json-variables-in-a-yaml-file-helm)

Comment: @edbighead that one is for json as a File. Not as a Stringified value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,'[{\"Key1\": value1}, {\"Key2\": 30}, {\"Key3\": "ABC"}]'